# Animate and export video over a time series in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, animation

I am trying to map a time series of Albedo, and then export it to a video. The mapping works fine, but I am getting the following error on the export:

> Error: ImageCollection must have 3 or 4 bands.

But there is only one band in each of the BlackSkyAlbedo features (images).

The code is included below:

```
//Map over the dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A3')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-10-01', '2018-05-01'));
var blackSkyAlbedo = dataset.select('Albedo_BSA_Band1');
var blackSkyAlbedoVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 400.0,
};
Map.setCenter(-111.475, 45.23, 6);
Map.addLayer(blackSkyAlbedo, blackSkyAlbedoVis, 'Black-Sky Albedo');

print(blackSkyAlbedo);
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-118.79,42.50, -106.0,47]);

// Export
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: blackSkyAlbedo,
  description: 'blackSkyAlbedo',
  dimensions: 720,
  framesPerSecond: 12,
  region: polygon,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
blackSkyAlbedo = blackSkyAlbedo.combine(blackSkyAlbedo).combine(blackSkyAlbedo)
.map(function(image) {
  return image.add(32768).divide(65536).multiply(255).uint8();
});
```

The export video only works on multiband (3- or 4-band) 8-bit int (0-255) image collections. You can combine the image collections together into itself twice, then map a function onto each image to convert to uint8.